# Recover files from previous .RData

Tags: r

I was having some problems loading the R workspace so I typed `unlink(".RData")` to clean it up. As a result of this (I guess) all my .R files have been restored to previous versions dating to ~3 weeks ago.
I am working from an Rstudio server linked on a linux cluster.

Is there any way to recover my .R files / .RData file?

Thanks in advance,
Gerard

Comment: .RData doesn't affect .R *files*; the relationship between them is like a donut compared to the recipe for a donut. Do you have other backups?

Comment: The nomenclature "unlink" is a bit of a misnomer here. The use of the term "unlink" sounds like it would just break the link between the work environment and the data, but `unlink()` deletes the files or directories that you specify. In short, your .RData is gone. You may be able to salvage some of your work environment objects by trawling through your .Rhistory file and rerunning any pertinent code.